# Script is slower when function is called from a file as opposed to when defined in the script

Tags: python, function, time

I have a script that solves an ODE model, `def odeModel(y,t):`, using scipy.integrate.odeint.

As I was timing the execution of the script, I found something weird, to me:  when I write out the definition of the odeModel inside the script, the script will execute in about 2.5 sec, however, when the odeModel is saved in a separate file, odeModel.py, and imported `from odeModel import odeModel`, the script will execute in about 10 sec.

Why is the execution of the script slower when I call the function from a separate file?

Comment: It might be something to do with the actual import, perhaps python is taking a while to find your separate file?

Comment: what happens if you replace `odeModel()` with just `return dummy_result` and measure the time performance in both cases again? Provide [mcve]

Comment: There appears to be something specific to odeModel, because the minimal example of printing `Hello World` from a function defined within the script or from another file take a similar amount of time to execute.  Let me think about it a bit more, and I will decide if I need to upload the whole script